# Gradle not getting resteasy dependency

Tags: gradle, resteasy, artifactory

I am trying to get "resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.9.Final.jar" into my application as a dependency with gradle via Artifactory, however gradle doesn't download it.

As you can see below if I download directly from MavenCentral it works as I would expect, if I go via Artifactory it skips resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.9.Final.jar.  What am I missing?

`build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin:'java'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
//  maven {
//      url "http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/repo1/"
//      url "http://artifactory:8081/artifactory/libs-release/"
//  }
}

dependencies{
    compile 'org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:3.0.9.Final'
}
```

**output of gradle dependancies**:

1. Direct from mavenCentral():

   - commons-codec-1.6.jar
   - commons-io-2.1.jar
   - commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
   - activation-1.1.jar
   - jcip-annotations-1.0.jar
   - httpclient-4.2.6.jar
   - httpcore-4.2.5.jar
   - jaxrs-api-3.0.9.Final.jar
   - jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar
   - **resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.9.Final.jar**
2. via Artifactory - is the same as above except:

   - <strike>resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.9.Final.jar</strike> **- this is missing**

I've not encountered any other issues with Artificatory so I'm a bit surprised by this one.

Here's a screenshot of the files cached in Artifactory, the lack of any jar files doesn't look right to me...
[image: Artifactory]

Comment: The console output you posted indicates that it is getting the dependency, just seems to be the wrong version. Can you post the output of `gradle dependencies`?

Comment: Looks like the POM artifact is in the repository but the jar is not. Gradle will attempt to download the artifact because it found the artifact descriptor (POM) and fail.

Answer (score 0):

The below is my build.gradle

Did you apply the java plugin. Because otherwise gradle does not understand 'compile'.

To check if it's working do a

```
gradle build
```

and then check your %rootDir%/build/libs/ , you can find your resteasy libs inside your resulting project jar file

```html
    apply plugin:'java'


repositories {

    mavenLocal()
//    maven {url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
//    maven{url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"}
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies{
    compile 'org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:3.0.9.Final'

}

jar {
    from configurations.compile.collect { zipTree(it)}
}
```

Comment: I'm getting different results when downloading direct from MavenCentral or Artifactory.  I've updated the post to reflect this.